# How to Update SharePoint File Title When Only Item ID is Available after Upload?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am working on a task to upload a file to SharePoint using the provided code. The file upload is successful, but I also need to update the title of the uploaded file. The SharePoint API requires the List ID to update the title, but in the response of the upload API, I only receive the Item ID.

Here is my code for updating the document title:

```
private async updateDocumentTitle(libraryId: string, itemId: string, title: string): Promise<void> {
  const client = await this.getClient();

  const fieldValueSet = {
    Title: title
  };

  await client.api(`/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/items/${itemId}/fields`).update(fieldValueSet);
}
```

And here is the code for uploading the file:

```
public async uploadDocument(
  name: string,
  content: any,
  contentLength: number,
  folderName: string,
  originalName: string
): Promise<string> {
  try {
    let libraryId = await this.getLibraryIdByLibraryName(folderName);
    if (!libraryId) {
      libraryId = await this.createLibrary(folderName);
    }
    const client = await this.getClient();

    const fileExtension = originalName.slice(originalName.lastIndexOf('.'));

    const uploadSession = await client
      .api(`/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/drive/root:/${name + fileExtension}:/createUploadSession`)
      .post({
        item: {
          '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior': 'rename'
        }
      });
    const { uploadUrl } = uploadSession;
    await axios.put(uploadUrl, content, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Length': contentLength,
        'Content-Range': `bytes 0-${contentLength - 1}/${contentLength}`,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      }
    });

    return '1.0';
  } catch (error) {
    throw new DocumentStorageException('Cannot upload document to SharePoint');
  }
}
```

How can I obtain the List ID in order to update the title of the uploaded file using the provided Item ID? Any help would be appreciated.

I took `list-id` from the SharePoint website by hardcoding list-id in `updateDocumentTitle`, and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking your method for uploading the file and you get `listId` by calling

```
let libraryId = await this.getLibraryIdByLibraryName(folderName);
```

Use the same code in `updateDocumentTitle` method.

```
private async updateDocumentTitle(folderName: string, itemId: string, title: string): Promise<void> {
  let libraryId = await this.getLibraryIdByLibraryName(folderName);
  const client = await this.getClient();

  const fieldValueSet = {
    Title: title
  };

  await client.api(`/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/items/${itemId}/fields`).update(fieldValueSet);
}
```

Comment: In SharePoint, a file has two unique Ids, listId(numeric) and itemId(uuid)
In response to upload, you get itemId, but in the updateDocumentTitle function, it takes listId ( although it is named as itemId), both are different.